# shell script, need help to check if file exists

Tags: bash, shell

I have two folders "downloads", and "files".  I want to move all .txt files form downloads to files.  before moving them to files folder, I check to see if it already exists in the "files" folder. If does not exist, then i will move them.

but for some reasons, my scripts always return  file does not exists.

```
#!/bin/sh

SOURCE_PATH="/Users/johnqin/Downloads/*.txt"
DEST_PATH="/Volumns/files/"

ls -l $SOURCE_PATH > /dev/null 2>&1

# check if there are any .txt files
if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then

    # loop through all .txt files
    for file in $SOURCE_PATH
    do
        # get only file name
        fname=`basename $file`
        #echo $fname

        targetFile="$DEST_PATH$fname"
        # echo $targetFile

        # check if this file exist in the target folder
        if [ -e "$targetFile" ]
        then
            echo "$fname exists, do nothing"
            # will do nothing
        else
            echo "$fname does not exist, move the file over"
            # will move file over
        fi
    done
else
    echo "did not find file"
fi
```

**UPDATE:**

I think I know what the problem is. my code is fine. "/Volumns/files" folder is a shared folder on another Ubuntu server. I auto mount this folder when I login.  The address of this folder is "smb://ubuntunas/files".

still need to figure out why my code works for other folders but not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compact version (note `find ... -maxdepth 1` and `cp -nv`)

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

readonly source=/home/bobah
readonly destination=/home/bobah/tmp
while read line; do
  echo 'name: ['${line}'], basename: ['${line##*/}']'
  cp -nv ${line} ${destination}
done < <(find ${source} -maxdepth 1 -name '*.cpp')
```

Output:

```
name: [/home/bobah/abc.cpp], basename: [abc.cpp]
name: [/home/bobah/test.cpp], basename: [test.cpp]
`/home/bobah/test.cpp' -> `/home/bobah/tmp/test.cpp'
```